Search for targets and indicate where they come from
I would like to search for the occurrences of the targets and present the result as shown in the image below using just one formula in M5, without dragging. --> Google Spreadsheet sample.
This is the closest that I get:
=join(" - ",transpose(ifna(QUERY(BYROW($D$5:$H$49, LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, $L5) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), ""))),"WHERE Col1 is not null"))))

But it does not populate the results.
Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated, thank you!


Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

@TheMaster Thank you. I shall take your advice into consideration.

If your current formula works, then use MAP() or BYROW() to make it dynamic spill array formula. Try-
=MAP(TOCOL(L5:L,1),LAMBDA(x,
join(" - ",transpose(ifna(QUERY(BYROW($D$5:$H$49, LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, x) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), ""))),"WHERE Col1 is not null"))))))

You can also use simplified formula using TEXTJOIN().
=MAP(TOCOL(L5:L,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("-",1,BYROW($D$5:$H$49, LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, x) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), ""))))))

And for A.x column use-
=MAP(TOCOL(L5:L,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("-",1,BYROW(HSTACK(SCAN("",C5:C49,LAMBDA(p,q,IF(q="",p,q))),$D$5:$H$49), LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, x) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), ""))))))

And you can combine two formula into one cell using HSTACK(). See you sheet Q5 cell.
=HSTACK(MAP(TOCOL(L5:L,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("-",1,BYROW($D$5:$H, LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, x) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), "")))))),
MAP(TOCOL(L5:L,1),LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN("-",1,BYROW(HSTACK(SCAN("",C5:C,LAMBDA(p,q,IF(q="",p,q))),$D$5:$H), LAMBDA(row, IF(COUNTIF(row, x) > 0, INDEX(row, 1), "")))))))



Let me post another fresh formula using MAKEARRAY().
=MAKEARRAY(ROWS(TOCOL(L5:L,1)),2,LAMBDA(r,c,
TEXTJOIN("-",1,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(HSTACK(SCAN("",C5:C,LAMBDA(p,q,IF(q="",p,q))),D5:D),3-c),INDEX(MMULT(--(E5:H=CHOOSEROWS(L5:L,r)),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(E5:H),1,1,0)))))))



Awesome, works perfectly! Thank you very much for responses.
